# How to pass selected value to php controller

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, model-view-controller

I am trying to pass selected value with ajax to php controller but its not working.
This is my code

```
function prodType() {
    
    $("#productType").change(function(){
        let value = $("#productType").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "<? echo URLROOT. '/AddProduct'?>",
            type:"GET", //not sure if this should be get or post
            data:{
                "optionValue": value
            },
            success: function(response){
                
            }
        });
    });
```

I'm sure its getting the value but it is not successfully passing it to the controller.

This is my controller

```
public function index(){
        $_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
        ...
    }
    /*If request method == Get, load view */
    else{
        $type = $_POST['optionValue']; //trying to get the value here
        $typeClass = ucfirst($type);
        new Display(new $type);
        var_dump($type); //getting null here
        $this->view('add');
     }
  }
```

This is my view

```
 <select id="productType" name="type" onChange="prodType();" required>
      <option value="" hidden>Select type</option>
      <option value="DVDType" >DVD</option>
      <option value="BookType" >Book</option>
      <option value="FurnitureType">Furniture</option>
    </select>
```

### Edited

I changed `type` from GET to POST and it still didn't work. I am thinking maybe my controller should be this instead

```
public function index(){
        $_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
        ...

$type = $_POST['optionValue']; //trying to get the value here
        $typeClass = ucfirst($type);
        new Display(new $type);
        var_dump($type); //getting null here
    }
    /*If request method == Get, load view */
    else{
        
        $this->view('add');
     }
  }
```

(Getting the value from ajax when the Server request method is POST). Since the value can only be set after the page has been loaded. But then i need the value to be before the form is submitted hence `$_POST` might not catch it. What am i missing?

Comment: "_//not sure if this should be get or post_" If you want to access `$_POST['optionValue']` this should be `POST`

Comment: It's pretty simple. If you use `type: 'POST'`, you get the value using `$_POST`. If you use `type: 'GET'`, then you get the value using `$_GET`.

Answer (score 2):

[As documented](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php), the `$_POST` array contains the "variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method".

Therefore, you should change your ajax-call to a POST-request:

```js
function prodType() {
    
    $("#productType").change(function(){
        let value = $("#productType").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "<? echo URLROOT. '/AddProduct'?>",
            type:"POST",
            data:{
                "optionValue": value
            },
            success: function(response){
                
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I have. Still didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "But then i need the value to be before the form is submitted hence $_POST might not catch it."?

Comment: Based on the selected option I want to display an additional input field. The field must be present before the form can be submitted. In a nutshell, I need ajax to pass the selected value to a php controller (which displays an additional input field depending on the value selected) that must be filled before the form can be submitted.

Comment: You cannot modify the already displayed form from PHP directly (without reloading the page the form is on). In that case, you would probably want to handle the logic of displaying and hiding the additional field entirely client-side in JS.